# Can't move in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am stuck in a small space in Bleak Falls Barrow, and I can't move, fast travel, or restart. What should I do?

The game will not let me fast travel and I will lose my progress if I load a new save.

Comment: When you say you can't "move", does that mean you can't do anything at all, like attack? Depending on the geometry, a combination of jumping and attacking can help you get un-stuck. Shouts like Whirlwind Sprint work well too, but since you're in Bleak Falls Barrow, it's likely you don't have any yet.

Answer (score 4):

Other than loading an old save your only real option is to resort to console commands. If you're not playing on PC, then I'm afraid loading an old save is probably your only option.

Open the Skyrim console by pressing the key below your escape button, on US keyboards this is a tilde key <kbd>~</kbd> and on UK it's <kbd>`</kbd>.

You can toggle your players collision with the environment using the `TCL` command, which should allow you to more through anything trapping you in place. Once in a safe location, use the same command to return to normal movement.

However if you are stuck in an area, rather than being stuck on some terrain, you can use the "Center on Cell" command by typing: `COC E3demoBleakFallsBarrow` which will teleport you to the spawn point for this location.

(You could also pick the COC code from [this list](http://www.skyrimsearch.com/categories/cells/1/Bleak%20Falls%20Barrow/), if you want to travel to somewhere closer to your current location)

Comment: é or " on some other keyboards. Still, it is the button under esc.

Comment: Wouldn't using tcl be easier to get out of a stuck situation?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Quite possibly, I will add that option to the answer. I think I originally read the question more like "I'm stuck in an area" rather than the character being stuck on terrain.